# Boolean.parseBoolean not working

Tags: android, arrays, local-storage, storage, saving-data

I am trying to save this boolean array. When I read the array the string array (parts) says that

```
     parts[0]=true;
```

,but when I use Boolean.parseBoolean array[0] is still false. Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong. Please and Thank You.

```
public void writeArraytofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("array.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(Arrays.toString(array));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}
public boolean[] read(){

String result = "";
boolean[] array = new boolean[2];
try {

    InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("array.txt");

    if (inputStream != null) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String tempString = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(tempString);
        }

        inputStream.close();

        result = stringBuilder.toString();

        String[] parts = result.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i]=Boolean.parseBoolean(parts[i]);

        }

    }


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.v("MyActivity", "File not found" + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //here you catch and watch the problem
    Log.e("MyActivity", "cant parse string: " + result);
}
return array;
}
```

Comment: 'parts[0] = true' wouldn't compile

Comment: @anomeric why not?

Comment: because it's a string array...

Comment: The very first thing I do when I provide input that doesn't get handled as I expected is to inspect the input to make sure it's what I thought it was. Did you think to check `parts[i]` to see what it contains when you pass it on to `Boolean.parseBoolean`? I'll bet it's not what you think.

Comment: Could you please show us the value inside variable `result`

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.toString()` will print brackets and commas, so when you read the string back in and call `.split(" ")`, the first piece will be `"[true,"`. Since that is not just `"true"`, `Boolean.parseBoolean()` will return `false`.